If I have a symbol obtained from a compilation, how do i find the same symbol in other compilation?
I just learned today that in Roslyn, each compilation has its own symbol which is different from the symbol in other compilations. For example, the symbol for class X in compilation A is different from the symbol for class X in compilation B, despite them being the same symbol (compilation B didn't have class X but referenced compilation A).
So my question is, if I get a symbol from a compilation, how do I find the same symbol in another compilation? I want to avoid creating my own code for that, so is there any method in Roslyn that I can use to do that?
I'm currently using Roslyn 3.11.0 for reasons that are too long to explain, so I want the answer for that version. But the answer for the newer version of Roslyn is fine.
